# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'userid')

Tags: node.js

I have this login route that checks the id and password and everything works well I tried to add 2 lines of code to save the user id after the login in a session and it shows me the error above in the title, this is the login route:

```
router.post('/login', async(req, res)=>{
const { id, password } = req.body;
try {
    //check for user id
    const user = await User.findOne({id: id})
    if(!user) res.json({message: "Invalid ID#"})
    //bcrypt.compare to check and compare the hashed password
    if(user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.pass))){
        
        const token = jwt.sign({
            id,
        }, "01021997", {
            expiresIn: "30d",
        })
        console.log(token)
        res.json({auth: true, message: "logged in succesfully", token: token})

        sess = req.session
        sess.userid = user.id;

    }else{
        res.status(400)
        res.json({auth: false, message: "Invalid ID# or password!"})
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
}
})
```

And ofc I declared the session above in the file "const session = require('express-session')"
and I also did the:

```
// creating 24 hours from milliseconds
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

//session middleware
app.use(sessions({
secret: "thisismysecrctekeyfhrgfgrfrty84fwir767",
saveUninitialized:true,
cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
resave: false
}));
```

And under it I declare a global variable "var sess" so that I use it in any route so idk why it tells me undefined and etc..

Comment: _"I declare a global variable"_. Don't. But that's not your issue, your issue is with `req.session` not being defined. The code you post doesn't provide a clue why that might be. It could be that you're adding the session middleware in the wrong order (_after_ your routes, for instance).

Comment: well i declared a global session cause i couldn't access the session from other routes when i declare it globaly, and btw i solved the problem, the only thing above my session middleware in my code was the app.use(express.json()) and the 
app.use(cors()) so i placed it above them and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to declare the session middleware before the json and cors like this:

```
// creating 24 hours from milliseconds
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

//session middleware
app.use(session({
secret: "thisismysecrctekeyfhrgfgrfrty84fwir767",
saveUninitialized:true,
cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
resave: false
}));
//this will allow us to recieve informations from the frontend in json 
format
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
```